# C program for compiler programming using yacc-lex

Tags: c, debugging, yacc, lex

This is a C program that is supposed to build a tree from input code in c using yacc and lex. the functions in the program makes the nodes for each function, variable, operator, number, etc. What it says is there are syntax errors or segmentation faults during run time. I have tried making changes but nothing seems to help. Could you point out the errors in the code:

```
typedef struct tnode{
    int val;
    char* var;
    char* strng;
    int type;
    int nodetype;
    struct Gsymbol *Gentry;
    struct tnode *left,*right, *mid;
   
}tnode;

struct Gsymbol
{ char* name;
  int type;
  int size;
  int binding;
  struct Gsymbol* next;
};
 
struct tnode* makeLeafNode(char *c, int n);
struct tnode* makevarnode(char *c, int t);

struct tnode* makenode(char *c,int t,char d,struct tnode *l,struct tnode *m,struct tnode *r);


struct Gsymbol* lookup(char* na);
void install(char* na, int ty, int si);
void view();


void postfix(struct tnode *t);



struct Gsymbol* head = NULL;

struct Gsymbol* tail = NULL;

int symadrs = 4096;


struct tnode* makeLeafNode(char* c, int n)
{
    struct tnode *temp;
    temp = (struct tnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
   
    if(c!=NULL)
      {temp->strng = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(c)+1));
       strcpy(temp->strng, c);
      }
    else
      temp->strng = NULL;
   
    temp->var = NULL;
    temp->val = n;
    temp->nodetype = 4;
    temp->type = 'i';
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->mid=NULL;
    temp->Gentry = NULL;
    return temp;
}

struct tnode* makevarnode(char *c, int t)
{
    struct tnode *temp;
    temp = (struct tnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
    temp->var = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(c)+1));
    strcpy(temp->var, c);
    temp->val = 0;
    temp->nodetype = t;
    temp->type = 'i';
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->mid=NULL;
    temp->strng = NULL;
    if(t==5 && c!=NULL)
     temp->Gentry = lookup(c);
    else
     temp->Gentry = NULL;
    return temp;
}

struct Gsymbol* lookup(char* na)
{ struct Gsymbol* temp = head;  
 
  if(na!=NULL)
   while(temp!=NULL)
    {
     if(strcmp(na, temp->name)==0)
      return temp;
     temp = temp->next;
    }
  return NULL;
 
}

void install(char* na, int ty, int si)
{  
    if(lookup(na) != NULL)
     {char er[100] = "Variable re-initialized: ";
      strcat(er, na);
      perror(er);
      exit(1);
      }
   
    struct Gsymbol* temp;
    temp = (struct Gsymbol*)malloc(sizeof(struct Gsymbol));
    temp->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(na)+1));
    strcpy(temp->name, na);
    temp->type = ty;
    temp->size = si;
    temp->binding = symadrs;
    symadrs+=si;
    temp->next = NULL;
   
    if(head == NULL)
       head = temp;
    else
      tail->next = temp;
    tail = temp;
}

void view()
{ printf("Name\t Type\t Size\t Binding\n");
  struct Gsymbol* temp;
  temp = (struct Gsymbol*)malloc(sizeof(struct Gsymbol));
  temp = head;
  while(temp!=NULL)
   { printf("%s\t %d\t %d\t %d\n", temp->name, temp->type, temp->size, temp->binding);
     temp = temp->next;
   }
 
}

/* type:
   0-read
   1-write
   2-connect
   3-operator
   4-num/string const
   5-var
   6-if
   7-while
   8-break
   9-continue
   
   dtype:
   i-int
   b-bool
*/


struct tnode* makeNode(char *c, int t, char d, struct tnode *l, struct tnode *m, struct tnode *r){
    struct tnode *temp;
    temp = (struct tnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
    temp->var = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(c)+1));
   
    if(t==3 && d=='i')
       if(l->type=='b' || r->type=='b')
         {printf("Type Mismatch\n");
          exit(1);
         }
         
    if(t==6 || t==7)
       if(l->type=='i')
         {printf("Type Mismatch\n");
          exit(1);
         }
   
    temp->val = 0;
    temp->nodetype = t;
    temp->type = d;
    temp->left = l;
    temp->right = r;
    temp->mid=m;
    temp->Gentry = NULL;
    temp->strng = NULL;
    strcpy(temp->var, c);
       
    return temp;
}

void postfix(struct tnode *t)
{
    if(t->type == 4)
    {  if(t->strng == NULL)
        printf("%d ",t->val);
       else
        printf("%s ",t->strng);
    }
    else if(t->type == 5 || t->type == 8 || t->type == 9)
    {
        printf("%s ",t->var);
    }
    else{
     
      postfix(t->left);
      if(t->type==6)
         postfix(t->mid);
      if(t->type == 3 || t->type == 2 || t->type == 6 || t->type == 7)
        postfix(t->right);
       
     
     
      printf("%s ",t->var);    
 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Show the commands you run, the input you use, if any, and the resulting output or error messages. You menstion lex and yacc, but don't show any source code related to these tools.

Comment: You can use debugger to pinpoint an exact location of the segmentation fault and read values of the variables at that point.